# Converting varchar values that were derived from a constant field to Month and Year

Tags: sql, date, sql-server-2016, varchar

I have a query where I am grabbing certain text out of a string.  An example of the string is:

"Captured Credit Card: MasterCard, xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx, 09/19. Set as Default."

My query is pulling the expiration month and year out of that text.

```
SUBSTRING(ADT.MsgText, CHARINDEX('/', ADT.MsgText, 0) -2, 2) AS [Month]
,'20' + SUBSTRING(ADT.MsgText, CHARINDEX('/', ADT.MsgText, 0) + 1, 2) AS [Year]
```

However, I need these number values to be recognized as date values.  I tried the following method, but was unsuccessful:

```
UPDATE CCC
SET CCC.[Month] = convert(date, convert(varchar(4), CCC.[Year]) + ' ' + convert(varchar(2), CCC.[Month]))
FROM CC_Captured CCC
```

The error message I get is: "Update or insert of view or function 'CCC' failed because it contains a derived or constant field."

I'm wondering how to convert these values to be date?
Any help is appreciated!

(Also I am using SQL 2016)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [DATEFROMPARTS](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/datefromparts-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) to construct a date in the month (first or last day of the month).

```
declare @MsgText nvarchar(1000) = N'Captured Credit Card: MasterCard, xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx, 09/19. Set as Default.'
select SUBSTRING(@MsgText, CHARINDEX('/', @MsgText, 0) -2, 2) AS [Month]
,'20' + SUBSTRING(@MsgText, CHARINDEX('/', @MsgText, 0) + 1, 2) AS [Year]
-- First day of the month
select DATEFROMPARTS(CAST('20' + SUBSTRING(@MsgText, CHARINDEX('/', @MsgText, 0) + 1, 2) as int), CAST(SUBSTRING(@MsgText, CHARINDEX('/', @MsgText, 0) -2, 2) as int), 1) as FirstDayOfMonth
-- Last day of the month - add 1 month to the date above and go back 1 day
select DATEADD(day, -1, DATEADD(month, 1, DATEFROMPARTS(CAST('20' + SUBSTRING(@MsgText, CHARINDEX('/', @MsgText, 0) + 1, 2) as int), CAST(SUBSTRING(@MsgText, CHARINDEX('/', @MsgText, 0) -2, 2) as int), 1))) as EndOfMonth
```

Or even better, use [EOMONTH](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/eomonth-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) function:

```
select EOMONTH(DATEFROMPARTS(CAST('20' + SUBSTRING(@MsgText, CHARINDEX('/', @MsgText, 0) + 1, 2) as int), CAST(SUBSTRING(@MsgText, CHARINDEX('/', @MsgText, 0) -2, 2) as int), 1)) as EndOfMonth
```

Comment: Thank you! This was very helpful!